# How to deal with setInterval in server tests

Tags: javascript, testing, asynchronous, setinterval, hapi.js

Lets say we are using setInterval inside of a hapi plugin, like so:

```
// index.js

internals = {
  storage: {},
  problemFunc: () => {
    setInterval((storage) => {
      storage.forEach((problem) => {
        problem.foo = 'bar';
      });
    }, 500);
  }
};

module.exports.register = (server, options, next) => {
  server.on('start', () => { // called when the server starts
    internals.storage.problem1 = {};
    internals.storage.problem2 = {};
    internals.storage.problem3 = {};
    internals.problemFunc(internals.storage);
  });
}
```

In our tests for this server, we may start up and stop the server many times to test different aspects of the server. Sometimes, we will get an error like `cannot set property 'foo' of undefined`. This is because the server gets shutdown right before that async code runs, and internals.storage.problem gets removed right along with the server stop.

This makes total sense, and I don't have a problem with that. I'd really like to know what would be some good ways to make sure my tests work 100% of the time rather than 90% of the time.

We could do:

```
problemFunc: () => {
  setInterval((storage) => {
    storage.forEach((problem) => {
      if (problem !== undefined) {  // check if deleted
        problem.foo = 'bar';
      }
    });
  }, 500);
}
```

or:

```
problemFunc: () => {
  setInterval((storage = {}) => {  // default assignment
    storage.forEach((problem) => {
        problem.foo = 'bar';
    });
  }, 500);
}
```

But I would rather not add conditionals to my code just so that my tests pass. Also, this can cause issues with keeping 100% code coverage because then sometimes that conditional will get run and sometimes it wont. What would be a better way to go about this?

Comment: Trying to reach 100% code coverage is so 90's like.

Comment: @DanFromGermany There's a difference between aiming for 100% and having a single test vary in the amount of coverage it provides each time it runs due to external factors.

Comment: @James Thorpe: Exactly. We could obviously comment out the conditional so that the coverage checker ignores it, but I'm looking for a clean way to do this rather than just anything that works.

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely normal to have slight differences in set-up and configuration when running code in a test environment.

A simple approach is to let the application know the current environment, so it can obtain the appropriate configuration and correctly set-up the service. Common environments are `testing`, `development`, `staging` and `production`.

Simple example, using an environment variable:

```
// env.js
module.exports.getName = function() {
  return process.env['ENV'] || 'development'
}

// main.js
if (env.getName() !== 'testing') {
  scheduleBackgroundTasks()
}
```

Then run your tests passing the `ENV` variable, or tell your test runner to do it:

```
ENV=testing npm test
```

Comment: I appreciate the response, but I don't feel that using environment variables really answers the question. In this example, the plugin should work the same regardless of what environment it is in, and it does work the way it's meant to. I feel that adding environment variables in a conditional would just be adding a layer of complexity to the first example solution I gave.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree: you have code that you don't want to run in a test environment, and this approach does exactly that. On the other hand, the solution proposed above will make you ignore legitimate errors, because you're asking if certain variables are initialized or not, which could happen by mistake (including timing errors, which are hard to track down). The real question is _am I testing?_, not _is this undefined?_